# render django url with #egbookmark

Tags: django, http, url, reverse, bookmarks

I'm at a loss on how I can render a view/template with a hashtag bookmark appended to the URL on page load.

For example, if my URL is `r'/mypage/$'` and my View is `return render(request, 'mypage.html')`, how can I have the URL on page load in the browser be: `/mypage/#something`? **The URL/View are not fixed, what I care about is rendering the page in the browser with the #something on it.** Note: I need to maintain the RequestContext.

I have visited tens of pages from StackOverflow, the Django docs and Lord Google with no success.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think render have that but possible with redirect...

```
return redirect('{}#something'.format(reverse('app:mypage')))
```

Comment: Interesting! This does in fact achieve the end result in the URL in the browser, unfortunately I cannot use this because I need to maintain the RequestContext.